# Magento 2 Is there a way to use Cyber Source Fraud Detection for Braintree Payments instead of Kount?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, payment, braintree, cybersource

We are using **Braintree** Payment Gateway and the **Kount** is out of the box feature of Braintree for Fraud Prevention and Detection.

For some reason, we want to move out of Kount and use **CyberSource Fraud Detection for Braintree**. Is there a way to do this?

I appreciate your thoughts. Thanks in advance.